# (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.)

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012, .net-4.5

I sometime get this error at client machine. Can anyone help what could be causing this?

```
A transport-level error has occurred when sending the request to the server. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.)
```

Here, i just read some data from database and filling my data table using data adapter. I am using SQL server 2012 and dotNet 4.5.

Stack Trace

```
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.WriteSni()
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.WritePacket(Byte flushMode)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ExecuteFlush()
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TdsExecuteRPC(_SqlRPC[] rpcArray, Int32 timeout, Boolean inSchema, SqlNotificationRequest notificationRequest, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean isCommandProc)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable dataTable)
at XXX.DatabaseFramework.SQLServer.SQLServerDBProvider.LoadDataTable()
```

Using below code, caused this exception

```
using (SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(this.Command)) { 
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable(); 
dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
return dataTable; }
```

Comment: can you post the code that caused the error?

Comment: @acutesoftware: Added the calling code